# Array has 1 value, how do I break up this large string?

Tags: php

My php array has an Array with 1 value.  Yet the string is rather large with whitespace.  I can't explode it as its a single value.  How can I break at that whitespace to put it in a table?

When I try to explode example:

```
$explode_output =  explode(' ',$counts);

print_r($explode_output);
```

I get the following result

```
Array ( [0] => 893 717 601 576 602 309 926 684 653 204 485 708 341 369 3 39 728 638 556 3 1011 639 476 593 672 773 307 738 587 505 539 467 683 610 760 841 721 734 431 793 867 491 586 581 577 414 299 235 )
```

Because I want to put this in a table with each string value on a unique row, my efforts of using the following didn't work.

```
"<pre>" .$output. "</pre>"
```

The above code separates the array/string by whitespace but I can seen put loop them in a unique rows within a table.

I thought I needed to explode the array/sting but the single value lists the entire string.

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: And why you cannot explode?

Comment: I don’t understand why you can’t explode it.

Comment: why not explode with space

Comment: $explode_output =  explode(' ',$counts);

print_r($explode_output);

Comment: Is this a PHP or a CSS question? Because you can easily solve that with CSS: `word-break: break-all; white-space: pre-wrap;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the spaces and explode it into array using preg_split method in PHP. It's similar to split() method, but it accepts regular expression. The below code can even split strings which contains one or more spaces between them

```
$yourArray = Array ("893 717 601 576 602 309 926 684 653 204 485 708 341 369 3 39 728 638 556 3 1011 639 476 593 672 773 307 738 587 505 539 467 683 610 760 841 721 734 431 793 867 491 586 581 577 414 299 235");

$arrayOfStrings = preg_split('/\s+/', $yourArray[0]);
echo "<table>";

for($i=0;$i<count($arrayOfStrings );$i++) {
   echo "<tr><td>".$arrayOfStrings [$i]."</td></tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
```

In your table you can now loop over the $arrayOfStrings.

Comment: This seems to have solved my issue.

Array ( [0] => 893 [1] => 717 [2] => 603 [3] => 576...

Answer (score 4):

You can easily explode it with explode() function:

```
$data =Array ( [0] => 893 717 601 576 602 309 926 684 653 204 485 708 341 369 3 39 728 638 556 3 1011 639 476 593 672 773 307 738 587 505 539 467 683 610 760 841 721 734 431 793 867 491 586 581 577 414 299 235 )

$exp_data = explode(" ",$data[0]);

for($i=0;$i<count($exp_data);$i++)
{
   echo "<tr><td>".$exp_data[$i]."</td></tr>";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$array = Array ( [0] => 893 717 601 576 602 309 926 684 653 204 485 708 341 369 3 39 728 638 556 3 1011 639 476 593 672 773 307 738 587 505 539 467 683 610 760 841 721 734 431 793 867 491 586 581 577 414 299 235 )
```

$newArray = explode(" ",$array[0] );